# Laravel passing data to page

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass data to Controller of Laravel. here is how I do that :
in PagesController::

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function contact(){

        $data="some random ";
        return view('contact',compact("data"));
    }
}
```

now in contact.blade.php  :

```
contact pages {{ $data }}
```

and it s hows

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

What may be a problam?

Comment: Please update your post with route you're using and full error message.

Comment: Route::get('contact','PagesController@contact');

Comment: The contact page works without problam, but need to pass data from controllel wich does not work

Comment: Please post full error message.

Comment: Alexy, there is only that error page comes apear " whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: You can look in logs. Or you could change environment to local too see full error messages.

Comment: Alexy,  can you provide me where are logs, I am new at Laravel, or how to change local...

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public function contact()
    {
        $data = 'some random';
        return View('contact')->with('data' , $data ); 
    }
```

make sure that the view works fine (if its inside a folder use  return View('foldername.contact')

make sure that your view name is contact.blade.php  (check uppercase letters)
and inside your view

this is my {{ $data }}

Comment: Thank you for reply, view name is contact.blade.php and I've already tried ur solution but still the same error, without those data it's working fine

Comment: in ur app config try enable debug and share a screenshot of the full error  here